# JSON formatting extra characters

Tags: php, python, json, git

I'm trying to send some JSON with Python through an API. It works, but it adds a bunch of funky characters, and I have no idea why or what they mean.

What I'm doing is converting this 'body' variable:

```
+++[git checkout hashhashhash]+++

+++[git diff --name-status master]+++

M       file.php

1 files changed.
```

to this:

```
body = {"body":"{{noformat}}{0}{{noformat}}".format(body)}
```

When that's done, 'body' becomes this:

```
{'body': '{noformat}\n+++[git checkout hashashashashash]+++\n+++[git diff --name-status master]+++\n\x1b[?1h\x1b=M       file.php\x1b[m\r\n\r\x1b[K\x1b[?1l\x1b>\n1 files changed.\n{noformat}'}
```

Which would be totally fine, except that this is what's posted after it's sent through the API:

```
+++[git checkout hashashashashashash]+++

+++[git diff --name-status master]+++

[?1h=M       file.php[m

[K[?1l>
1 files changed.
```

I haven't found out what's going on. What is the deal with the `[?1h=M` and the `[K[?1l>`, and how do I make them go away?

Comment: Looks like ANSI escape codes to switch colours on the terminal. `git-diff` takes a `--no-color` switch to suppress those.

Comment: It has nothing to do with json. `print(repr(body))` to see that the ANSI escapes are already there. Where does  the `body` come from? btw, do not use the same name for different purposes in the same context e.g., `body` is used twice and it creates confusion in this case. (to disambiguate: in my question I meant `body` that you pass into `format()`, not the result dict).

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find those are terminal initialization sequences being sent by git - `function-key-mode on` and `function-key-mode off` to be precise.

Try using the `--no-pager` option when producing your original Git output.